# Add custom but specifc layout itemdecoration between recyclerview items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

I have a list of message objects that are being displayed in a recycler view as normal

```
@Entity(tableName = "messages")
data class Message(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "message_id")
    var messageId: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "body", defaultValue = "")
    var body: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "msg_type")
    var msgType: Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "message_date", defaultValue = "")
    var messageDate: String
)
```

How ever i want to implement a feature like whatsapp, that by scrolling between messages you can see a message date view like "02 May" that appears only if two messages have messageDate a different day. Should i use a customItemDecoration? But again i can't
How can i implement that?

Comment: You could use a sectioned `RecyclerView` and group your messages by date, check out https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter for example

Comment: Hm...yeah it could be. But im sure whatsapp does not do that this way! I think it could be more natively...